# How does async manual failover mode handle data sync issues?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2019

In async AG, with no automatic failover, what happens if the primary fails to harden the log to disk (due to say power failure), and secondary has received the log record and hardened it?

So, when the primary is up again, then does primary redo or does the secondary undo that record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the primary failed before the transaction committed to it, then it'll undo the transaction as part of recovery.

When the secondary connects to the primary and they exchange recovery forks, the secondary will need to undo back to one of the primary replicas recovery forks.

Comment: When secondary connects back to primary, and if the primary doesn't have the log record (due to a log backup), then will the sync break?

Comment: @variable It will not be able to sync, there will be an error on the secondary saying there isn't enough log to continue.

Comment: Won't the primary log truncation be prevented until the AG technology confirms that the secondary has synced?

Comment: @variable Depends on what issue occurs and what actions the administrator takes, if any. By default, yes, the log should be held up.